# differences between routed events and attached events and what differences they make?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am just going through the WPF concepts I came across these routed events ,dependency properties and attached events. 
I think I am not able to understand the concepts behind them and why they were being called in the place of .net originated methods?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Routed Events provide the ability for different controls in the element tree to react to events.

For instance, if we have a `Window` containing a `StackPanel` containing a `Button` and someone presses the mouse key on the button, the events will be fired in this order:

```
PreviewMouseDown on Window
PreviewMouseDown on StackPanel
PreviewMouseDown on Button
MouseDown on Button
MouseDown on StackPanel
MouseDown on Window
```

These "preview" events use a behavior called `Tunneling`. The normal events `Bubble` up again.

If you set the `Handled` property of the `EventArgs` to `true`, the tunneling and bubbling will stop. Tunneling or Bubbling is called the **Routing Strategy**.

This enables handling a variety of situations, for instance:

- Preventing any child element of the StackPanel to receive mouse down events. (Set `Handled` to `true` on `StackPanel.PreviewMouseDown`).
- Handling key presses on a Window that have not been handled by any other control (`Window.KeyDown`)

I would advise not looking into [Attached Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613550.aspx) untill this becomes absolutely necessary. The scenario's for attached events are very limited. Attached events are also routed events.